# PictureBox se mueve cuando no debe en evento MouseDown c#

Tags: c#, eventos, clase, picturebox

Buenos días!

Tengo un problema con una aplicación que estoy desarrollando. Tengo mi propia clase que hereda de PictureBox, con varios eventos. Entre ellos un MouseDown y un MouseMove.

El caso es que cuando pulso sobre ese objeto de mi clase, quería que el ratón se moviese al centro del pictureBox y luego empezar a moverlo desde esa posición central.

El problema que tengo es que una vez hago click sobre él, el puntero se mueve aparentemente al centro del pictureBox, pero arrastra con él al pictureBox, entonces el puntero del ratón se queda en la misma posición dentro del pictureBox, pero con el pictureBox y el ratón un poco movidos en esa búsqueda del centro del mismo.

Pongo mi código para aclararlo un poco más:

Método que coloca el objeto

```
    public void Colocar(Control control, Unidad unidad, Point p)
    {
        unidad.Location = p;
        control.Controls.Add(unidad);
    }
```

Evento MouseDown

```
bool clickPerformed = false; 
    bool clickMove = false; //Para saber si hay que moverlo
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Size.Width / 2, this.Location.Y + this.Size.Height / 2);

        clickPerformed = true; 
        Control tempSender = this.Parent; 
        tempSender.Invalidate(); 
        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        clickMove = true;
    }
```

Evento MouseUp:

```
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Parent.Invalidate();
        clickMove = false;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
```

Método para dibujar un círculo alrededor:

```
    public void DrawCircle(Graphics g, Pen pen, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius + radius, radius + radius);
    }
```

Evento MouseMove:

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (clickMove)
        {
            Left = e.X + Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            Top = e.Y + Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

A alguien se le ocurre alguna posible solución? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: A primera vista, diría que si eliminas el evento `onMouseMove` debería funcionar, ya que en el estás moviendo el picturebox dependiendo de el movimiento del ratón.

Comment: Ya, pero necesito el evento onMouseMove para poder mover la imagen después. Lo que quiero es que cuando el puntero del ratón se posicione en el centro del pictureBox, la imagen no se mueva, sólo se coloque ahí el ratón.

Comment: Ah, no había leido la parte de que usabas un control heredado. Prueba entonces a cambiar en el MouseMove `if (clickMove)` por `if (!clickMove)`, ya que no quieres mover el picturebox mientras el boton esté pulsado

Comment: No, no, quiero moverlo mientras esté pulsado, lo que no quiero es que se mueva cuando hago click, sino que se mueva mientras esté pulsado. La ejecución sería la siguiente: click -> colocar ratón en el centro del pictureBox sin mover imagen -> mover imagen mientras se mantiene el click, una vez colocado el puntero en el centro del pictureBox

Comment: Entonces en el onclic del boton calcula la posicion donde quieres mover el raton, cambias la posicion de raton, tanto la x como la y y activas una bandera. en el onmouseMove compruebas esa bandera para moverlo o no. y una vez has dejado de moverlo, al soltar el click pones la bandera a false.

Comment: La bandera no funciona igual que el bool que tengo? No seguiría teniendo el mismo comportamiento?